# Decode hex string to latin characters

Tags: php, hex, decode

I have string:

```
&#x74;&#x6f;&#x6d;&#x61;&#x73;
```

there is decoded string `tomas`

I found that there is hec decode type : http://www.codetable.net/unicodecharacters

Does in PHP exists fuction to encode hex to latin characters ?

Comment: [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not hex characters, but HTML entities.

PHP can decode them with [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).